# How parallel merge sort in python 2.7?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've tried to parallel merge sort in python 2.7 but I can't do it. Because I don't know if I should implement with thread or multiprocessing. Please write parallel code in thread or multiprocessing this codes:

```
def merge(left, right):
result = []
i ,j = 0, 0
while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
    print('left[i]: {} right[j]: {}'.format(left[i],right[j]))
    if left[i] <= right[j]:
        print('Appending {} to the result'.format(left[i]))           
        result.append(left[i])
        print('result now is {}'.format(result))
        i += 1
        print('i now is {}'.format(i))
    else:
        print('Appending {} to the result'.format(right[j]))
        result.append(right[j])
        print('result now is {}'.format(result))
        j += 1
        print('j now is {}'.format(j))
print('One of the list is exhausted. Adding the rest of one of the lists.')
result += left[i:]
result += right[j:]
print('result now is {}'.format(result))
return result

def mergesort(L):
print('---')
print('mergesort on {}'.format(L))
if len(L) < 2:
    print('length is 1: returning the list withouth changing')
    return L
middle = len(L) / 2
print('calling mergesort on {}'.format(L[:middle]))
left = mergesort(L[:middle])
print('calling mergesort on {}'.format(L[middle:]))
right = mergesort(L[middle:])
print('Merging left: {} and right: {}'.format(left,right))
out = merge(left, right)
print('exiting mergesort on {}'.format(L))
print('#---')
return out

mergesort([6,5,4,3,2,1])
```

Thank you.

Comment: You know that none of this code runs, right? Either you copied and pasted it from somewhere random, or you just messed up the formatting

Comment: "please write parallel code in thread or multiprocessing this codes" Is that an order?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was about to ask the very same question :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 , Isn't an order dear user.it's just help but if you can!

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would say that probably neither threads nor multiprocessing will necessarily speed things up.

In CPython the global interpreter lock ("GIL") makes sure that only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecode. This is done to make memory management easier, among other things. So assuming the data to be sorted is in memory, threads will not make this faster because only one thread at a time is actually working on it.

Unless you use shared memory like `multiprocessing.Array` for your data, multiprocessing needs to pickle data and send it to child processes for them to work on it. And child processes do the same to send it back. The larger the dataset, the more overhead this incurs. And an `Array` uses locking to serialize access. *This is a good thing, but it can slow you down.* You could use a `RawArray` that doesn't use locking, but then you'd have to be very careful with modifying data.

The best approach I can think of is the following. In this case the data you can sort is limited to whatever `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` accepts.

- You create two `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` instances, A and B. The array A contains the unsorted data, the array B (which is equally sized to B has all values set to 0.
- If your CPU has N cores, you create a `multiprocessing.Pool` with N workers (this is the default). Then you create a sequence of tuples that divide the indexes of the array in N contiguous parts. Say you have an array of 16 values, and N=4. Then the sequence would be `((0,3), (4,7), (8,11), (12,15))` Then you call the `Pool.map` method on the given sequence. Each worker then receives a tuple that indicates which part of the shared arrays it is supposed to work with.
- Each worker reads the part of the A list it is responsible for, sorts the data and writes the sorted data to the same part of the B list.
- Finally, the parent process puts the four parts of the B array in the correct order.